# Best practise for changing existing API functionality

Tags: c++, api, design-patterns

i am wondering about the best way of changing an existing code functionality that belongs to a large library-project. Let's have an simple example:

```
Class A {
public:
    A() {}
    void init() {
        a_comp = archive::compressor::zip;
    } 

private:
    archive::compressor* a_comp;
};
```

What would be the best way of changing the a_comp attribute from `archive::compressor::zip` to `archive::compressor::rar` if the existing code doesn't offer a setter for it?

If I would just *derive from A and override the init() implementation*, i cant't make sure that all api functionality uses the rar instead oft the zip.

Is there a way of doing so without touching the original code?
(want to keep things easy in case of update)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I guess you'll have to dust off the old time machine ;)

Comment: What is the declaration of `archive::compressor::zip` and `archive::compressor::rar`?

Comment: Preprocessor macros like `#if THIS_LIBRARY_ISAVAILABE` archive::compressor::zip *a_comp; #else archive::compressor::rar *a_comp;`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you gave us, I'd say, that the API isn't designed to be extended.

If the getter for `e_comp` isn't private, you could try extend `A` and override the getter of `e_comp`. If not, you can't change it in any way, that may be called *good design* or *design pattern*.

There might still be some tricky c++ hacks, to enforce `archive::compressor::rar` anyway.